# Is there a bijective map from $\mathbb Q/ \mathbb Z$ to $[0,1]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Could we define a bijection map between $\mathbb Q/ \mathbb Z$ to real interval $[0,1]$?

Any comments and guidance are welcome.

Comment: Is $\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z$ countable or uncountable? Is $[0,1]$ countable or uncountable?

Comment: By $\mathbb Q/ \mathbb Z$ you mean the quotient space?

Comment: Yes, and elements of this group is given by $p/q+ \mathbb Z$.

Comment: And how does it work? We have to define an equivalence  relation between quotients' elements.

Comment: Not for nothing, since you are talking about an *isomorphic* map, how would you define your group structure on $[0,1]$? Or are you just assuming there exists one?

Comment: As a topological space and quotient space, could we define it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. For one, we know that any map $\mathbb{Q} \to [0, 1]$ is not onto (domain is countable, $[0, 1]$ is uncountable). If there were an onto map $\mathbb{Q} / \mathbb{Z} \to [0, 1]$, then we could construct an onto map $\mathbb{Q} \to [0, 1]$ as follows: If $f : \mathbb{Q} / \mathbb{Z} \to [0, 1]$ is onto, then define $g : \mathbb{Q} \to [0, 1]$ by $g(x) = f(x + \mathbb{Z})$.

However, it is true that a set-bijection exists from $\mathbb{R} / \mathbb{Z} \to [0, 1]$, as well as $\mathbb{R} / \mathbb{Q} \to [0, 1]$, although neither bijection can be continuous.

EDIT: An earlier edit of this comment said that there existed no bijection $[0, 1] \to \mathbb{R} / \mathbb{Q}$, which is false, as pointed out in a comment. It is now correct, I believe. If there existed a continuous bijection $f : \mathbb{R} / \mathbb{Q} \to [0, 1]$, and $g$ was its inverse, then $g$ would be continuous. This would imply that $[0, 1]$ and $\mathbb{R} / \mathbb{Q}$ are homeomorphic, which is false because, for instance, $[0, 1]$ is Hausdorff where $\mathbb{R} / \mathbb{Q}$ is not Hausdorff.

Comment: I don't know what I was thinking a year ago, but you're right.

Comment: Yes, it seems correct now.

Answer (score 5):

There isn't. $\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z$ has countably many elements, while $[0,1]$ has uncountably many elements.

Comment: Could we define a topology on these sets and define a homeomorphic map? You can find this topic on youtube  taught by njwildberger.

Comment: @B.K-Theory A homeomorphic map must be bijective, so we couldn't.